# the Derived Column Transformation editor in an SSIS 2008 Data Flow not filtering as expected

Tags: ssis

I am trying to filter  a specific  string in a data flow using an expression in a Derived Column Transformation task.
The string I am trying to filter out is

```
0 0 0 0
```

However what is outputted is not NULL but

```
0 0- 0- 0
```

I have tried  a number of expressions, a few samples are below

```
[MSTUB-xInt_Only-Rev-Dt] == "0" + " " + "0" + " " + "0" + " " + "0" ? NULL(DT_WSTR,10) : SUBSTRING([MSTUB-xInt_Only-Rev-Dt],5,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([MSTUB-xInt_Only-Rev-Dt],3,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([MSTUB-xInt_Only-Rev-Dt],1,2)
```

and

```
[MSTUB-xInt_Only-Rev-Dt] == "00000000" || [MSTUB-xInt_Only-Rev-Dt] == "0 0 0 0" || [MSTUB-xInt_Only-Rev-Dt] == "0 0- 0- 0" ? NULL(DT_WSTR,10) : SUBSTRING([MSTUB-xInt_Only-Rev-Dt],5,4) + "-" + SUBSTRING([MSTUB-xInt_Only-Rev-Dt],3,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING([MSTUB-xInt_Only-Rev-Dt],1,2)
```

Here  are inputs  to the transformation task
MSTUB-xInt_Only-Rev-Dt
0 0 0 0
1052013

Here are outputs
MSTUB-xInt_Only-Rev-Dt
 0 0- 0- 0
01/05/2013

It seems there is an issue recognizing the spaces between the 0s?
Any guidance on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here is  an example of the input data

Comment: there might be spaces after or before the string; try trimming before the compare e.g. trim([MSTUB-xInt_Only-Rev-Dt])=="0 0 0 0" ...

Comment: Hi Jayvee, perfect...the TRIM solves the issue, thank you

Comment: that's great. I wrote the solution in the answer box so you can accept it and  close the question.

Answer (score 0):

there might be spaces after or before the string; try trimming before the compare e.g. trim([MSTUB-xInt_Only-Rev-Dt])=="0 0 0 0" ...

Comment: Or Do a replace on the space " " with no space "" then you should be left with just "0000"